# change the size of a mask to a direction with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mask

I want expand the width of a mask with animation.

This is my code:

```
func addPointsToProgressBar(points : CGFloat) {
    let oldBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame.width, height: 50)
    let maskWidth = Int(Float(progressBarFillImage.frame.width) * levelProgress())
    let newBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maskWidth, height: 50)

    var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: oldBounds)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: newBounds)
    animation.duration = 2.0

    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame = newBounds
    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "expandWidth")
}
```

The animation is working and the mask is expanding to left and right directions equally. The thing is that I want it to expand from right to left (it's a progress bar loader).

How can I do it?

Comment: levelProgress() method for calculating the progressWidth ?

Comment: @vigneshkumar yes this just gives a fracture

Answer (score 1):

To animate from right to left you can apply transform in negative x direction or you can follow your current code with slight modifications like below

```
func addPointsToProgressBar(points : CGFloat) {

    var oldBounds = progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame
    let maskWidth = CGFloat(Float(progressBarFillImage.frame.width) * levelProgress())
    let extended = maskWidth - progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame.size.width
    let newX = oldBounds.origin.x - extended;
    let newBounds = CGRect(x: newX, y: 0, width: maskWidth + extended, height: 50)

    var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: oldBounds)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: newBounds)
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.setValue("progressAnimation", forKey: "id")
    animation.setValue(maskWidth, forKey: "originalMaskWidth")

    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame = newBounds
    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "expandWidth")
}

override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    if (anim.valueForKey("id") as! String) == "progressAnimation" {
        progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (anim.valueForKey("originalMaskWidth") as! CGFloat), height: 50)
    }
}
```

I have modified 'newBounds' such that the rightmost edge of the rect is rooted and moving the x position further left to the amount of increased progress.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the progress view type animation what you do is increase the width of the mask and then move its x which will be half of the width u have increased. See this as example

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.6, options:
UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

    println("Animation function animateStuff() started!")
    var frmPlay : CGRect = self.buttonPlay.frame

    let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
    let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y

    let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
    let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

    self.buttonPlay.frame = frmPlay

    self.buttonPlay.frame = CGRectMake(
        originXbutton - 50,
        originYbutton,
        originWidthbutton+100,
        originHeightbutton)

    }, completion: { finished in

})
```

or you can modify your core just be decrease the X cordinate of newBounds

```
func addPointsToProgressBar(points : CGFloat) {
    let oldBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame.width, height: 50)
    let maskWidth = Int(Float(progressBarFillImage.frame.width) * levelProgress())
    let increasedWidth = maskWidth - progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame.width
    let xShiftedTo = oldBounds - increasedWidth
    let newBounds = CGRect(x: xShiftedTo, y: 0, width: maskWidth, height: 50)

    var animation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGRect: oldBounds)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGRect: newBounds)
    animation.duration = 2.0

    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.frame = newBounds
    progressBarFillImage.layer.mask.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "expandWidth")
}
```